# Links in PDF displayed in WKWebView not working after UIWebView migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I've recently migrated from using UIWebView to WKWebView. I'm having difficulty getting my app to behave in the same way as before. It used to go to another view controller when a link in the PDF was tapped, but since migrating links are not working at all.

The app used to check for links being pressed with `if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)` however after replacing this with `if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated)` it never steps into the statement when links are pressed.

When an attempt to click a link occurs, I get the following in the console:

```
WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 3, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1002
```

My up-to-date WKWebView code:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    
    NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[navigationAction.request.URL query]];
    
    if ([[requestUrl absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {
        NSRange start = [[requestUrl absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"ios:webToNativeCall_STAR_ID_"];
        NSString *webRowId;
        if (start.location != NSNotFound) {
            webRowId = [[requestUrl absoluteString] substringFromIndex:start.length];
        }
        
        // Call the given selector
        [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall:) withObject:webRowId];
    }
    else {
        [self _saveSearch];
    }

    
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
        // FOLLOWING LINE NEVER CALLED
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestUrl options:[NSDictionary new] completionHandler:nil];
    }
    

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Old UIWebView code:

```
//- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
//                                                 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
//
//    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {
//
//        NSRange start = [[[request URL] absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"ios:webToNativeCall_STAR_ID_"];
//        NSString *webRowId;
//        if (start.location != NSNotFound) {
//            webRowId = [[[request URL] absoluteString] substringFromIndex:start.length];
//        }
//
//        // Call the given selector
//        [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall:) withObject:webRowId];
//        // Cancel the location change
//        return NO;
//    }
//    else {
//        [self _saveSearch];
//    }
//    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
//        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]
//                                           options:[NSDictionary new]
//                                 completionHandler:nil];
//        return NO;
//    }
//
//    return YES;
//
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify if condition and check if it works

```
if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestUrl];
   decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
   return;
}
```